# Add shipping class to body class on WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I wish to have added the shipping classes as a body class on the checkout page.

It would be best if all active shipping classes is added, but otherwise add a specific class if a certain shipping class is present in the cart.

Can anyone help me with this.. all other guides I can find only relates to remove rates/shipping options, so really hope for some help here.

Comment: You should remove (delete) [your same question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/345181/woocommerce-add-shipping-class-to-body-class) from Wordpress Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will add the product(s) *(cart item(s))* shipping class(es) as additional body class(es) tag(s) on checkout page:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_shipping_classes_to_body_class' );
function add_shipping_classes_to_body_class( $classes ) {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
            // If a shipping class is set for the product, we add it to body classes
            if ( $shipping_class = $item['data']->get_shipping_class() )
                $classes[] = $shipping_class;
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: @jlock You should remove (delete) your same question from Wordpress Stack Exchange. You can do it clicking on "delete" text button below your question.

Comment: I tried that, but now allowed to delete it since there has already been answers.