# Add a body class for specific chosen shipping method in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

Based on *[Add a body class for specific selected shipping option in Woocommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864038/add-a-body-class-for-specific-selected-shipping-option-in-woocommerce-checkout/48866704#48866704)* answer code, I have been using the following code snippet for some time:

```
add_filter( 'wp_footer','weekend_selected' );
function weekend_selected(){
    if( ! is_page( 8 ) ) return; // only on checkout

    $method_id = "''";
    // Find the Shipping Method ID for the Shipping Method label name 'Delivery price on request'
    foreach( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $rate_key => $rate ){
        if( 'Saturdays DPD' == $rate->label ){
            $method_id = $rate_key;
            break;
        }
    }
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                // variables initialization
                var a = 'input[name^="shipping_method[0]"]',
                    b = a+':checked',
                    c = 'weekend-selected',
                    d = '<?php echo $method_id; ?>';

                if( $(b).val() == d )
                    $('body').addClass(c);
                else
                    $('body').removeClass(c);

                $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', a, function() {
                    if( $(b).val() == d )
                        $('body').addClass(c);
                    else
                        $('body').removeClass(c);
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

However I have noticed that it does not trigger anymore on page load, I have to refresh the page for it to trigger which is making it useless.

The use case is basically to load a body tag (weekend-selected) which then hides (with CSS) certain days on a calendar.

First I thought it was because the shipping options were not loading before an address was added so I prefilled required address fields to see if this was the problem but the same thing happens, I have to refresh the page for the code to trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following simple and light way *(without using Jquery)*:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_shipping_classes_to_body_class' );
function add_shipping_classes_to_body_class( $classes ) {
    // only on checkout page
    if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) 
        return; 
        
    $chosen_method  = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0];
    $shipping_rates = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'];
   
    if( 'Saturdays DPD' === $shipping_rates[$chosen_method]->label ){
        $classes[] = 'weekend-selected';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better works.

Related: [Add shipping class to body class on WooCommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507357/add-shipping-class-to-body-class-on-woocommerce-checkout-page/57507510#57507510)

Comment: Thank you. Just getting an error on line 10 -'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context

Comment: Thanks, I removed the line if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) 
        return;  as it is causing problems. Other than that it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't saying your code does not work, just that line is conflicting with something on the website. I will accept it. Thank you.